# Undefined reference to WinMain (C++ MinGW)

Tags: c++, winapi, mingw, mingw32, winmain

Currently, I am trying to make a Windows application using C++. For compiling my program I use MinGW (GCC). But as soon as I use `int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)` instead of `int main()` the compiler shows me the following message:

```
C:/mingw-w64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o):crt0_c.c:(.text.startup+0x2e): undefined reference to `WinMain'
 collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1
```

The example code I tried to compile I got from this Windows application tutorial:

[Example Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/your-first-windows-program)

I have already tried reinstalling MinGW but it did not help (also I'm using Windows 10).

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/prepare-your-development-environment

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Newer Mingw versions support `-municode` linker option switching to alternate startup code allowing to use `wWinMain` instead of `WinMain` (or `wmain` instead of `main`). Add it to your command line, linker options in IDE or makefile.

```
g++ other_options_and_arguments -municode
```

Older versions do not support this option.

> One thing to note is that Visual C++ supports a “wWinMain” entry point
> where the “lpCmdLine” parameter is a “LPWSTR”. You would typically use
> the “_tWinMain” preprocessor definition for your entry point and
> declare “LPTSTR lpCmdLine” so that you can easily support both ANSI
> and Unicode builds. However, the MinGW CRT startup library does not
> support wWinMain, so you’ll have to stick with the standard “WinMain”
> and use “GetCommandLine()” if you need to access command line
> arguments.

via [Building Win32 GUI Applications with MinGW](https://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/computing/win32-apps-with-mingw/)

In this specific case, you can use `WinMain` instead. This program doesn't use `pCmdLine` value, so it should compile when you change `wWinMain` to `WinMain` and `PWSTR pCmdLine` to `PSTR pCmdLine`.

If you later would need unicode command line use `LPWSTR cmd_line = GetCommandLineW();` instead of `WinMain` argument.

Answer (score 16):

The solution is to add `-municode` to the compilation parameters, as mentioned by @ssbssa in a comment. (In the meantime, the accepted answer has been updated, and confirms this).

Example:

```
g++ helloworld3.cpp -o helloworld3 -Wl,-subsystem,windows -municode
```

See https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/wiki2/Unicode%20apps/

> While it is not necessary to define _UNICODE or UNICODE to compile the above code, -municode is needed for linking because it uses wmain() instead of the traditional main().

Comment: "-municode" is actually a parameter to the linker, "ld.exe" ?

Answer (score 4):

> undefined reference to `WinMain'

It tries to find `WinMain` and failed. So you need use `WinMain` instead of `wWinMain`.

Another possible issue is

> error: conflicting declaration of C function 'int WinMain(HINSTANCE,
>   HINSTANCE, PWSTR, int)'  int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
>   HINSTANCE, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
>               ^~~~~~~ In file included from c:\mingw\include\windows.h:44:0,
>                    from test.cpp:5: c:\mingw\include\winbase.h:1263:14: note: previous declaration 'int WinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPSTR,
>   int)'  int APIENTRY WinMain (HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int);

So you need use `LPSTR` instead of `PWSTR`.

Then the entry point will like this:

`int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, LPSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)`

Above is ANSI version entry point.

Comment: `int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)` you forgot `hPrevInstance`

Answer (score 3):

I use mingw-w64 for Windows 10 (64 bit).

If you use this win32 [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/your-first-windows-program):

Change

```cpp
int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow);
```

to

```cpp
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
```

then compile it with

```
gcc -O2 -Iinclude -std=c99 -D UNICODE -D _win32_IE=0x0500 -D WINVER=0x0500 hw.c -s  -Wl,--subsystem,windows -municode  -lcomctl32 -D WIN_32_LEAN_AND_MEAN -c
```

and link it with:

```
gcc hw.o
```

Answer (score -1):

I was using vscode and answer to my problem was :

1. open setting
2. search save
3. enable save file before run

terminal will work properly

Comment: What is the relation between this answer and that question?

Comment: I was getting error while running CPP file on vscode .

Comment: The question is about an error in compiling a c++ code. There is nothing to do with the autosave feature of some editors.

Comment: No, he is right to an extent, the aforementioned error often appears when the file has not been saved so you are compiling an empty file. The autosave feature means this is will not ocurr.