# C++ code showing error sometimes in VS Code sometimes and not others

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, gcc

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    cout << "Welcome to this video"<<"\n";

    int a;
    a = 10;

    switch (a) {
        default:
        cout << "default is executed whatever happens";  
        case 10:
        cout << "a is 10" << "\n";
        case 5:
        cout << "a is now 5" << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is my code. When I am trying to comment line:

```
default:
cout << "default is executed whatever happens";
```

and then when I am saving and running the code I am getting the error

```
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o):crt0_c.c:(.text.startup+0x2e): undefined reference to `WinMain'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

But when I am closing and opening my terminal 2-3 times and then running the code, my code is working fine after 2-3 attempts. Similarly when I am uncommenting the commented code and when I am trying to run it I am getting error:

```
tempCodeRunnerFile.cpp:1:7: error: expected unqualified-id before 'default'
       default:
```

Can anyone please tell me why C++ is working like this. I am using VS code as my code editor and my GCC version is 8.1.0.

Comment: I don't know if that's what causing your main problem, but you should have a `break` in every case

Comment: Even if I add break above errors are still coming and I have to execute my code 2-3 times after saving it so that it can run properly

Comment: Unrelated note: ["using namespace std;", bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: Have a look at this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58324230/undefined-reference-to-winmain-c-mingw

Comment: I am a beginner in C++ .I do not have much understanding of bad practices in C++. Thankyou for telling me that

Comment: @alonkh2 Why is it working after not working for 2-3 times?

Comment: I really don't know. Might have to do with your system architecture? I see that the directory is called mingw-w64 - do you maybe have a 32bit architecture? That's my best guess

Comment: No I have 64bit architecture

Comment: @Ash There is no problem with being a beginner. Most of the beginners use bad practices unintentionally. But as long as you keep learning and start to avoid bad practices then you're good to go. In this case, you should not get used to using `using namespace std;` since it will be hard for you to stop writing it later in your career. Better to grow some of the good habits from the start than to try to ditch them a year later.

Comment: You are correct

Comment: Yes, like @digito_evo mentioned, you'll thank yourself if you stop `using namespace std` right now. **IF** the reason you're using it is to save time writing things like `cout` you could instead `using namespace std::cout, std::string;`. Also another quick note, `\n` counts as a single character, so you could very well write something like this: `std::cout << "Text" << '\n';`. Doesn't really change anything but I thought I'd mention it.