# I am beginner and the code can not be compile. I am trying to program with visual studio code. I don't know what is the problem?

Tags: c, powershell

```
#include<stdio.h> 

int main() {      

    printf("my name is Lakpa Titung");     
    return 0;      
}
```

```
Windows PowerShell Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights
reserved.

Install the latest PowerShell for new features and improvements!
https://aka.ms/PSWindows

PS C:\Users\user\C programming> gcc coading.c
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xa0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
PS C:\Users\user\C programming> ./a.exe
./a.exe : The term './a.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, 
or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the 
path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ ./a.exe
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (./a.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException       
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS C:\Users\user\C programming>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58324230/undefined-reference-to-winmain-c-mingw

Comment: To be portable, the minimum signature for `main` is `int main(void) {... return 0; }`.  Other than that there is nothing you've show that should not compile.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Undefined reference to WinMain (C++ MinGW)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58324230/undefined-reference-to-winmain-c-mingw)

Answer (score 0):

your code is totally right but at compile time it shows the error like:
Windows PowerShell Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights
reserved.

Install the latest PowerShell for new features and improvements!
https://aka.ms/PSWindows

**then go to:**
*setting-extension-Run code configuration- Click on Run in terminal and also click on Save befor Run..*..

your setting has done.
Rerun your code.