# How to resolve: undefined reference to 'WinMain'

Tags: c, makefile

I am new to programming in C and I am currently trying test to see if my linked list working correctly but I keep running in to the following error whenever I use my Makefile:

```
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o):crt0_c.c:(.text.startup+0x2e): undefined reference to \`WinMain'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:2: NodeStruct] Error 1
```

I made sure to save all my files and to have a main function included.

All files I am working with:

NodeStruct.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "linked_list_utils.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){ 
    Node* root = NULL;
    insert_end(&root, "hello");
    for(Node* curr = root; curr !=NULL; curr = curr->next){
        printf("%s\n", curr->x);
    }
    deallocate(&root);
    return 0;
}
```

linked_list_utils.h

```
#ifndef LIST_H
#define LIST_H

typedef struct Node{
    char *x;
    struct Node* next;
}Node;

void insert_end(Node **root,  char x[]);

void deallocate(Node** root);
#endif
```

linked_list_utils.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "linked_list_utils.h"

void insert_end(Node **root,  char x[]){
    Node * newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if(newNode == NULL){
        exit(1);
    }
    newNode->next = NULL;
    newNode->x = x;

    if(*root == NULL){
        *root = newNode;
        return;
    }

    Node* curr = *root;
    while(curr->next != NULL){
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    curr->next = newNode;
}

void deallocate(Node** root){
    Node* curr = *root;
    while(curr != NULL){
        Node* aux = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
        free(aux);
    }
    *root = NULL;
}
```

Makefile

```
NodeStruct: NodeStruct.o linked_list_utils.o
    gcc -o NodeStruct.o linked_list_utils.o
NodeStruct.o: NodeStruct.c linked_list_utils.h
    gcc -c NodeStruct.c
linked_list_utils.o: linked_list_utils.c linked_list_utils.h
    gcc -c linked_list_utils.c
clean:
    rm -f *.o *.exe
```

Comment: Maybe duplicate?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58324230/undefined-reference-to-winmain-c-mingw

Comment: It's strange, because the default option should be to build a console application. Try adding `-mconsole` to your `gcc` options.

Comment: Depending on what libraries you’re using you _may_ have to link libmingw32. For example, SDL requires this.