# Cross compile cython with zig cc

Tags: cython, cythonize, zig

Is there a way to cross compile **cython** project with **zig cc**.
According to this [blog](https://andrewkelley.me/post/zig-cc-powerful-drop-in-replacement-gcc-clang.html) **zig** can cross compile.
An example which cross compiles [cython hello world](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/tutorial/cython_tutorial.html) would be great.

Comment: There is a possible starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70474888/5769463 which uses using MinGW-w64 for cross compilation. Never used zig cc, so your millage may vary but the overall framework should be very similar.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need the python headers for the target.

Once you have them, you should be able to run:

```
# Compile .pyx to .c
cython helloworld.pyx
# Use zig to compile+link
zig build-lib -dynamic -target x86_64-windows \
   -I mingw-w64-x86_64-python/mingw64/include/python3.10/ \
   -lc \
   mingw-w64-x86_64-python/mingw64/bin/libpython3.10.dll \
   helloworld.c
```

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was specify `CC="zig cc"` in the same line as my `cythonize` command with `Cython==3.0.0b3`. For example:

```
CC="zig cc" cythonize -i -3 --no-docstrings ./my_cython_module.pyx
```

This produced the `.c` and `.so` files.

---

Fwiw, I had installed Zig as `sudo snap install --classic --beta zig`.